# Does Burnout have cross-platform multiplayer? 

Tags: burnout

Do the Burnout multiplayer servers allow cross-platform play?

Comment: As far as I know that does not exist at all for xbox360 as everything must be connected to Microsoft Live.

Comment: Are you talking about Burnout: Paradise?  Or some other entry in the series?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, no Burnout game has cross-platform functionality, although it was mentioned as a possible feature when being developed.

Answer (score 1):

No. Only 360 game that was cross-platform with PC was Shadowrun. I think Portal 2 is the only ps3 title cross-platform between ps3 and pc. There is no cross-console play that i know of with any game.